# How do I add asyncio task to pyqt5 event loop so that it runs and avoids the never awaited error?

Tags: python, tcp, pyqt5, python-asyncio, coroutine

I am new to asyncio and I want to leverage it for my pyqt application to handle communication over a tcp connection.

I made this trivial demo to learn how to deal with the QT loop in asyncio context. I have seen other post related to this but they are much more complicated than what I am trying to do at the moment. So I start the server client in a separate window so it listens and I try to send a message through my simple button click event on my widget. As barebones as it gets.... My problem is it does not work.

I am looking to be able to a single exchange of info and a case where the port is left open for a stream. I think these tasks would be straight forward in asyncio but having it play nice with qt seems difficult at this point.

right now I am getting

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'PushButton.sendmessage' was never awaited
  rslt = self.__app.exec_()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
```

I am not sure where to start on fixing this.

**test.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, pyqtSlot
import sys
import asyncio
from asyncqt import QEventLoop
from async_client import tcp_echo_client


class PushButton(QWidget):

    loop = None

    def __init__(self,app_loop):
        super(PushButton,self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.loop = loop

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PushButton")
        self.setGeometry(400,400,300,260)
        self.send_bttn = QPushButton(self)
        self.send_bttn.setText("SEnd Message")      
        self.send_bttn.clicked.connect(self.sendmessage)
        self.send_bttn.move(100,100)
        
    @pyqtSlot()    
    async def sendmessage(self):
        run_command = asyncio.create_task(tcp_echo_client("hey",self_loop))
        asyncio.run(run_command)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)  # NEW must set the event loop    sys.exit(app.exec_()) 
    
    ex = PushButton(loop)
    ex.show()
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()
```

the simple echo client routine

```
import asyncio


async def tcp_echo_client(message, loop):
    reader, writer = await asyncio.open_connection('127.0.0.1', 8889,
                                                   loop=loop)

    print('Send: %r' % message)
    writer.write(message.encode())

    data = await reader.read(100)
    print('Received: %r' % data.decode())

    print('Close the socket')
    writer.close()
```

and the responding server

```
import asyncio

async def handle_echo(reader, writer):
    data = await reader.read(100)
    message = data.decode()
    addr = writer.get_extra_info('peername')
    print("Received %r from %r" % (message, addr))

    print("Send: %r" % message)
    writer.write(data)
    await writer.drain()

    print("Close the client socket")
    writer.close()

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
coro = asyncio.start_server(handle_echo, '127.0.0.1', 8889, loop=loop)
server = loop.run_until_complete(coro)

# Serve requests until Ctrl+C is pressed
print('Serving on {}'.format(server.sockets[0].getsockname()))
try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass

# Close the server
server.close()
loop.run_until_complete(server.wait_closed())
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that if you invoke a slot that is a coroutine then you must use the `asyncSlot` decorator, also do not use `ayncion.run()` but `await`(In addition to eliminating other *typos*).

```py
import sys
import asyncio

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton

from asyncqt import QEventLoop, asyncSlot
from async_client import tcp_echo_client


class PushButton(QWidget):

    loop = None

    def __init__(self, loop=None):
        super(PushButton, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("PushButton")
        self.setGeometry(400, 400, 300, 260)
        self.send_bttn = QPushButton(self)
        self.send_bttn.setText("SEnd Message")
        self.send_bttn.clicked.connect(self.sendmessage)
        self.send_bttn.move(100, 100)

    @asyncSlot()
    async def sendmessage(self):
        await tcp_echo_client("hey", self.loop)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    loop = QEventLoop(app)
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    ex = PushButton(loop)
    ex.show()
    with loop:
        loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Also, `x = asyncio.create_task(...)` followed by `await x` is superfluous, it could just be `await tcp_echo_client(...)`.

Comment: @user4815162342 That is what I was thinking but I did not want to change much the part that was not the cause of the error, thanks for helping me improve my post.

Comment: You're welcome, no problem. Note that I don't know enough (or really anything) about Qt's integration with asyncio, so I can't tell whether either variant will work correctly - for example, is it ok to await the potentially long-running `tcp_echo_client` from an async slot? Also you have a `=` in `sendmessage` left over from the previous version.

Comment: @user4815162342 This is exactly what asyncSlot does: it launches a task when it is invoked, what connects to the signal is an coroutine wrapper.

Comment: @eyllanesc why dont I pass in the loop into the form. I noticed that you took it out with ```self.loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()```